# What is the difference between async and steam writing files?

Tags: node.js

I now that it's possible to use `async` methods (like `fs.appendFile`) and streams (like `fs.createWriteStream`) to write files.

But why do we need both of them if streams are asynchronous as well and can provide us with better functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you're downloading a file, a huge file, 1TB file, and you want to write that file to your filesystem.

You could download the whole file into a buffer in-memory, then `fs.appendFile()` or `fs.writeFile()` the buffer to a local file, or try, at least, you'd run out of memory.

Or you could create a read-stream for the downloading file, and pipe it to a write-stream for the write to your file-system:

```
const readStream = magicReadStreamFromUrl/*[1]*/('https://example.com/large.txt');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('large.txt');

readStream.pipe(writeStream);
```

This means that the file is downloaded in chunks, and those chunks get piped to the writeStream (which would write them to disk), without having to store it in-memory yourself.

That is the reason for Streaming abstractions in general, and in Node in particular.

---

1. The `http` module supports streaming in this way, as well as most other HTTP libraries like `request` and `axios`, I've left out the specifics of how to create a read-stream <s>as an exercise to the reader</s> for brevity.

Comment: You mean if I use async method for writing a file (not stream) I will have to upload the hole file into RAM at first and then write it. And if I use stream I will do that with chunks? without a need to complete upload in RAM

Comment: Consider how you'd write a file with an async method, `fs.writeFileAsync('some-file.txt', text)`, `text` in its entirety is in memory.